# Cannot persist session scope bean entity using repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, session

I'm trying to persist a session scoped shopping cart into hibernate but I can't seem to do so since the persisted shopping cart in the DB is different from the one in the session, is there a way to fix this?

```
@SessionScope
@Service
public class AuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Autowired
private Cart cart;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
    user.setCart(cart);
    System.out.println(cart.getTest());
    // shopping cart is not the same as the autowired one
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    System.out.println(cart.getTotal());
}
}
```

User Class

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Cart cart;
```

Shopping Cart class

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Entity
public class Cart implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CartItem> cartItems;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "cart")
private User user;

private long test;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the one-to-one mapping and a reference on both sides of the association, try setting the User in the Cart along with your line

```
user.setCart(cart);
cart.setUser(user);
```

The already persisted Cart may need to be removed at that point if you have foreign key constraints.  Also not-null constraints on the foreign key may impact how you clean up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Turns out, I fixed out by not persisting the session cart directly but to create a new cart and persist that instead.